# How to sort an array in a single loop?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort, heapsort

So I was going through different sorting algorithms. But almost all the sorting algorithms require 2 loops to sort the array. The time complexity of Bubble sort & Insertion sort is O(n) for Best case but is  O(n^2) as worst case which again requires 2 loops. Is there a way to sort an array in a single loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "one loop" vs. "two loops".  You mean you want to sort without nested loops?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is counting or bin sort, but those require that all of the values be within a predefined range.

Answer (score 11):

Here, a single-loop Bubble Sort in Python:

```py
def bubbly_sortish(data):
    for _ in xrange(len(data)**2):
        i, j = _/len(data), _%len(data)
        if i<j and data[i] > data[j]:
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]

A = [5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10]
bubbly_sortish(A)

print A
```

Of course this is a joke. But this shows the number of loops has little to do with algorithm complexity.

Now, if you're asking if it is possible to sort an array with O(n) comparisons, no, [it's not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list). The lower bound is Ω(n log n) for comparison-based sorting algorithms.

Comment: Sure it's possible.  The quantum bogosort algorithm is O(n)!

Comment: @MrSmith42 That's bogosort.  Not quantum bogosort.

Comment: @Tripp Kinetics: Ok but you cannot implement it on a usual computer because you need all these universes. So for all now existing computers the lower bound Ω(n log n) is still valid.

Comment: @MrSmith42 The universes exist already.  The hard part is destroying **this** universe if the array isn't sorted.  Besides, algorithms are a concept independent of computers.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Not really. Algorithm complexity is intrinsically tied to the machine model the algorithm is supposed to run on. Would you say there are polynomial algorithms for all NP problems? But for a non-deterministic Turing machine this is just true. But no one says that. Even if bogosort could be solved by a "traditional" quantum computer, it would be in BQP, not P (necessarily)... and I think we got this joke just too far :)

Comment: @TrippKinetics, there's absolutely no need to *destroy* the universes where the data isn't sorted. *Someone* will be in the one where they *are* sorted :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
int list[] = { 45, 78, 22, 96, 10, 87, 68, 2 };
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] < list[i - 1]) {
            list[i] = list[i] + list[i - 1];
            list[i - 1] = list[i] - list[i - 1];
            list[i] = list[i] - list[i - 1];
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Sorted array is : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the general case you have O(n lg n) as an average.

But in particular cases, the best case is O(n), which I consider close enough to what you'd call "only one loop", even though the implementation may show more than one instance of the `for` keyword. And the good news with that, is that you're not depending on luck to make your best case a reality. Provided you know a few properties about your data, you can pick some specific algorithms. For example :

- 3-way quicksort runs very near O(n) when you have a lot of items with only a few distinct sorting keys (think server log entries as items and dates as keys).
- Counting sort runs in O(n+k) if your keys are easily indexable (like a character set, or small integers), and the index has a known upper bound k.
- Burstsort will run in O(wn) if you're dealing with strings of maximum length w.

Those are but three examples. There are many more, way too many to recall from the top of my head, for many types of constrained data sets.
 If you have a real-life case at hand where O(n lg n) is not good enough, it's well worth doing some proper research, **provided you identified a few interesting properties in your data**.

Comment: Bear in mind that O(n lg n) is an average, not a lower bound.  The lower bound is O(n) when the input is already sorted :)

Comment: You're right, this was a bad mistake ! I'll correct my post immediately. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Single Loop Bubble Sort using C++

```
int a[7]={5,7,6,2,4,3,1};

int temp = 0;

int j = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i<a[]-1 ; i++)
{
    int flag = 0;
    if(a[i]>a[i+1])
    {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = temp;
        flag = 1;
    }       
    if(i == 7-2-j)
    {
        if(!flag) break;
        i = -1;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment (inside!) your code (know [Doxygen](www.doxygen.org)?), use a symbolic constant for the number of `a`s elements, and a telling name instead of `flag`.

Comment: People should mind that this is a specific array that can be sorted by one iteration of bubble sort.

Answer (score 2):

```
javascript:
function bruteForce(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length; ){
        if(arr[i+1]< arr[i]){
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = temp;
            i--;
            if(i === -1) i=0;
        }else i++;
    }

    return  arr;
 }

alert(bruteForce([2,3,4,5,6,23,1,1]));
```

Copy the code and paste in URL of the browser and hit enter. If the `javascript:` is missed then add it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to sort array using only single loop.

```
var array = [100, 110, 111, 1, 3, 19, 1, 11, -10]
var i = 1

while i < array.count - 1 {
    if array[i] > array[i + 1] {
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
        i = -1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
print(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version for your given example:

One very fast efficiant and logical way of doing the problem works if you know the range of the values to be sorted, for example 
`0 <= val <= 100` where val is integer.

Then you can do it with a single read and write operation in only two loops... one for reading the array, one for writing it sorted:

Use a second array where the indices represent values 0-100, store in it the number of times every value 0-100 is encountered, for example `val = 100` could exist 234 times in your target array...

There is only one loop for reading and one loop for writing, which is computationally as efficient as one loop which would do both the reading and the writing and faster than a loop that uses comparison... If you insist, you can do it in a single loop twice as long as the target array's length and reset i value to zero on the new array write operation.

The second loop simply writes in order the count of every value encountered in the first array.

Comment: This (known as a [pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort)) is the only true example of a single loop sort that operates in O(n) time. Like any other sorting example, a loop is required to display the results, but only after the sorting is complete.

Comment: According ot Wiki, Pigeonhole sort is a mathematical concept rather than a programming array process, although pigeonhole sorting of arrays is very common. I used this solution to sort 10 million points in less than 1-2 seconds, its very easy to program and has near maximum efficiency for num instructions, it is literally 12 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Single loop array sort:

```
for(int i = 0, j=i+1; i < arr.length && j<arr.length;)
    {       
        if(arr[i] > arr[j])
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;              
            i=0;
            j=i+1;
        } 
        else
        {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sortArrayUsingSingleLoop(int[] intArray) {
        int temp;
        boolean swap = false;
        for(int i=0;i<intArray.length-1;i++){
         if(intArray[i]>intArray[i+1]){
             temp=intArray[i];
             intArray[i]=intArray[i+1];
             intArray[i+1]=temp;
             swap=true;
         }

         if(swap &&i==intArray.length-2){
            i=-1;swap=false;
         }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**The following code is in php. you can test the code on https://paiza.io/projects/4pAp6CuB-e9vhGIblDNCZQ.**

```
  $a = [8,3,4,9,1];
    for($i=0;$i<count($a)-1;$i++){
        if($a[$i] > $a[$i+1]){
            $temp = $a[$i];
            $a[$i] = $a[$i+1];
            $a[$i+1] = $temp;
            $i = -1;
        }
    }
    print_r($a);
```

Comment: It could be helpful if you added some context to your answer.

Comment: This is essentially bubble sort in what language? Could be perl or shell script without context, people have a hard time understanding.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the context. The following code is in php. you can test the code on http://phpfiddle.org.

Comment: @puneetjain Edit the answer with the above comment. Comments are for reviewers not for additional info from the author. You could additional use Edit1/Edit2/ etc markers in case of unrelated info to the answer to a specific comment. Happy using SO.

Answer (score 1):

public class SinleLoopeSorting {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] x = new Integer[] { 1, 7, 8, 0, 4, 2, 3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) {
            int p = x[i];
            x[i] = x[i + 1];
            x[i + 1] = p;
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have edited your question. But a tip for next time would be that if you're posting a code then use the given alignment option for better understanding.

Comment: What is the addition to all the other suggestions starting the index at 0 and resetting it to -1? (If and when you edit the question, please fix the formatting of the code block. I found it least cumbersome to just enclose code with lines containing `~~~`, the first one mentioning the language as need be.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be used to sort array usinga single loop:-
Points to be noed:

1. updating the value of i to -1 so that it alwasy starts from 0 after i++
2. reducing the length(size--) of array as maximum valued element ends up at the end for every time the loop completes

**Code:**

```
void sort(int *arr,int size){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <size; i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            arr[i]=arr[i]+arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=arr[i]-arr[i+1];
            arr[i]=arr[i]-arr[i+1];
            if(i==size-2){
                printf("%s\n","inside if loop" );
                i=-1;
                size--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single `for` loop for insertion sort:

strong text

```
function insertionSort (array) {
    for(var i = 1 ; i < array.length ;){
        if(array[1] < array[0]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i -1];
                array[i -1] = temp; 
         }
        if(array[i] < array[i-1]){
            var temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[i -1]
            array[i -1] = temp
            i--
        } else{i++}
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: Voted down for not mentioning the language and presenting a redundant conditional statement in deviant syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_sort(num_list):
    x = 0
    while x < len(num_list) - 1:
        if num_list[x] > num_list[x+1]:
            num_list[x], num_list[x+1] = num_list[x+1], num_list[x]
            x = -1
        x += 1
    return num_list

print(my_sort(num_list=[14, 46, 43, 27, 57, 42, 45, 21, 70]))
#output [14, 21, 27, 42, 43, 45, 46, 57, 70]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array using single loop (javascript)

```
var arr = [4,5,2,10,3,7,11,5,1];
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
{       
    if(arr[i] < arr[i-1])
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1];
        arr[i-1] = arr[i] - arr[i-1]; 
        arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[i-1];              
        i=0;
    } 
}
```

output : arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 10, 11]

Answer (score 0):

**The following code is in PHP to sort an array best case possible.**
https://paiza.io/projects/r22X0VuHvPQ236jgkataxg

```
<?php
function quicksort($a){
    $n = count($a);
    $lt = [];
    $gt = [];

    if($n < 2){
       return $a;
    }else{
        $f = $a[0];
    }

    for($i = 1;$i < $n ;$i++){
        if($a[$i] > $f){
            $gt [] = $a[$i];
        }else{
            $lt [] = $a[$i];
        }
    }

    return array_merge(quicksort($lt),array($f),quicksort($gt));
}


$ar = [7,4,3,6,5,1,2];
echo "Input array => ".implode(' , ',$ar).'<br>';
$a = quicksort($ar);

echo "Output array => ".implode(' , ',$a);;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array using java in Single Loop:

```
    public int[] getSortedArrayInOneLoop(int[] arr) {

    int temp;
    int j;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        j = i - 1;

            if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {

            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            i = 1;

            }

        }

    return arr;

    }
```

Comment: Output for {3, 2, 1}: `[2, 1, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but hope this helps

java solution

```
for(int i=1;i< arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[i-1] ){
            arr[i-1] += arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i-1] - arr[i];
            arr[i-1] -= arr[i];
            i=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: This saves two tokens compared to starting the loop index at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not O(n)

```
def sort(array):
    n = len(array);
    i = 0;
    mod = 0;
    if(len(array)<= 1):
        return(array)

    while n-1:
        if array[mod] > array[mod+1]:
            array[mod], array[mod+1] = array[mod+1], array[mod]

        mod+=1
        if mod+1 >= n:
            n-=1
            mod = 0

    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void sort(int a[],int n,int k,int w)
    {   
      int i,j,z,key;
      n=n-1;
      j = k+1;
      key = a[j];
      i = j-1;
      while(i>0 && a[i]>key)
      {
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        i = i-1;
      }
      a[i+1] = key;
      k = k + 1;
      if(n!=0)
      {
       sort(a,n,k,w);
      }
    }

  int main()
 {
    int i,n,w,k=1,z=5,g;
    printf("enter the size of an array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    g=n;
    int a[n];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    w = n;
    sort(a,n-1,k,w);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
 }
```

Here is the solution. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int find2ndLargest() {
    int[] arr = {1,3,14,25,7,20,11,30};
    int temp;

    // sort array
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++) {
        if (arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
            i=0;
        }
    }
    return arr[arr.length-2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] sort(int[] arr){
        int idx = 0;
        int len = arr.length - 1;
        int counter = len;
        while(true){
            if(idx != len && arr[idx] > arr[idx+1]){
                swap(arr, idx, idx + 1);
                counter--;
            }
            idx++;
            if(counter == len && idx == len){
                break;
            }
            if(idx == len){
                idx = 0;
                counter = len;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }


    void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it as much simple as below, please flow easy step

```
         var arr=[5,1,4,3];
             for(var i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
                 var num=arr[i];
                 var num2=arr[i+1];
                //Check if first index value with next index value
                if(num>num2){
                  var temp=arr[i];
                  arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                  arr[i+1]=temp;
                  //assign i=0 to re start the loop to check the index value
                  i=0;
                 }
             }
```

console.log(arr)

Comment: not working with same number comes in the arr

Answer (score 0):

> you can use a while loop and play around with the index

```
       int i=0;
       int a[]={1,2,3,4,7,3};
       while(i<a.length)
       {
           if((i+1<a.length && a[i]>a[i+1]) )
           {
                swap(i,i+1,a);
               i=i-1;
           }
         if(i-1>=0 && a[i]<a[i-1] )
             {
             swap(i,i-1,a);
            i=i-1;
             }
           else
               i++;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Code

```
func sortingOneArray(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var sortedArray = array
    var i = 0
    while (i < sortedArray.count - 1) {
        if sortedArray[i] > sortedArray[i+1] {
            let temp = sortedArray[i]
            sortedArray[i] = sortedArray[i+1]
            sortedArray[i+1] = temp
            print("i \(i)")
            i = 0
        } else {
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
    return sortedArray
}

print(sortingOneArray(array: [1,3,7,4,2,0]))
```